# I can't build the extension for joomla

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I am following the instructions from https://github.com/corePHP/wp-for-joomla and trying to build the extension but I got the same error:
com_wordpress not found.

WordPress for Joomla 4.5 > build:

WordPress for Joomla 4.5 > cleanup:

```
 [echo] Deleting existing package folder...
```

[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57\build\packages
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57\build\packages
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57\build\packages\compressed

WordPress for Joomla 4.5 > export_repo:

WordPress for Joomla 4.5 > package_component:

```
 [echo] Building component...
```

[phingcall] C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57\build\build.xml:54:38: Directory C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57\build\export\src\administrator\components\com_wordpress not found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57\build\build.xml:20:41: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.

Total time: 0.9196 seconds

C:\Users\PC\Desktop\wordpressForJommla\wp-for-joomla\wp57

any ideas will be thankfull

Comment: What version of PHP are you building with?

Comment: I used 8.1.8 and php 7.4

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.